# Opencv configuration issue

Tags: python, opencv

I have recently installed opencv 2.4.8 on my raspberry pi.When i check the version with

```
pkg-config --modversion opencv
2.4.8
```

But in my python code when i import cv2 i am getting the error as no module named cv2.I have checked my usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages and it is empty. How to solve the issue?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't installed the Python bindings.

Comment: how can i install the python bindings. Is there way to get them as zip file instead of sudo apt-get??

Comment: @DanNixon can a pip command be used to install python packages??